# Confusion in understanding proof of theorem "between any two reals, there is one rational"

Tags: real-analysis

I am in little confusion while understanding the proof of theorem 1.20 (b), from 'Principles of Mathematical Analysis' by W. Rudin. I am also writing what I think but I am not sure if I am going in correct direction.  Statement says " If $x \in R, y \in R$ and $x<y$, then there exists a $p \in Q$ such that $x<p<y$. Here $R$ is real field and $Q$ is set of rational numbers and author has mentioned that whatsever your structure of real field is ( like it can be our normal real number line or it can be in the form of cuts), we can always have isomorphic copy of $Q$ hidden in $R$. So "p" in the above statement is actually corresponding image of some rational number and that's why $x<p<y$ makes sense.( Am I correct here?). Author uses part (a) in the proof of part (b). Part (a) says " If $x\in R, y\in R$, and $x > 0$, then there is a positive integer n such that $nx > y$. Here term $'nx'$ means $' x + x +.....+x '$(n times), where $+$ is addition operation. Now at the start of proof of part (b), using part (a), author furnishes positive integer n such that $n(y-x)>1$. I have doubt in next line. Author has again applied part (a), to obtain integers $m_1$ and $m_2$ such that $m_1> nx$ and $m_2> -nx$. I didn't get how author applied (a) here. Also 'nx' is in $R$, $m_1$ is integer, I think $m_1$ is viewed as it's isomorphic image in $R$ here but not sure about it. I have thought about it for quite long time now but still in confusion. Thanks.

Comment: $1>0$, so there is a positive integer $m_1$ such that $m_1\times1>nx$. But $m_1\times1$ is just $m_1$.

Comment: Gerry Myerson..I thought about this but wasn't sure. I have one very silly doubt that's why I was not sure about it. This is my doubt. Let R be real field constructed by author consisting of cuts. Let $x\in R$. Now consider $x+x+x$. We write this term for convenience as $3x$. Now I am looking at term $3x$ from different point of view. 3 is integer here, now look at 3 as image in $R$ under isomorphic copy of rationals in $R$, which is nothing but rational cuts ( means 3 correspondence to $3^*$..set of rationals less than 3), now is $3^* × x$ is same as $3x$.

Comment: I mean is it true that $ 3x= x + x + x = 3^* × x$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson..can you please check my doubt in above comment